# Can you use "Both" alone in this case?

Tags: phrase-usage

If somebody tells me :

> Do you like summer or winter ?

Is it correct if I answer :

> Both.

Or am I forced to say :

> Both of them.

Thank you.

Comment: Just _both_ is fine, and likely more casual. _Both of them_ is also fine, though.

Comment: @jimsug: I don't see that adding *"of them"* makes the response any less "casual". It's still just a "cut-down" reply with no subject or verb, after all.

Comment: Did they use rising or falling intonation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @jimsug said, they are both fine.

The word *both* functions as a pronoun in both of your responses: "Both." and "Both of them."

I'd like to quote this explanation along with an important usage note from [Macmillan dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/both):

> **Both** can be used in the following ways:
>   as a **determiner** (followed by a noun, but not by a pronoun): Both children are at school.
>   as a **predeterminer** (followed by a word such as "the," "this," "his," etc.): I like both these pictures. ♦ Both her children are boys.
>   as a **pronoun**: Both arrived at the same time. (followed by "of"): Both of them are learning English. (after a noun or pronoun subject): The twins both have black hair. (following a pronoun object): I like them both. (after a modal or auxiliary verb, or after the verb "to be"): We can both speak Spanish. ♦ They are both good singers.
>   in the expression **both...and...**: a method that is both simple and effective
>
> Usage note: both
>   Do not use **both** in negative sentences. Use **neither**: Neither of my parents wanted me to leave school (=my mother did not and my father did not).